# Extending the static class : Uncaught TypeError: Super expression must either be null or a function

Tags: javascript

I am confused with extended class and `static`.

There are two `static` classes `Main1` `Main2`, both are extended from `Base` class.

And each has the variable `val`. `Manin1.val` and `Main2.val` should be different value independently.

These are my source code below.

```
class Base{
    static val;
    static initialize(x){
        this.val = x;
    }
}
class Main1 extends Base{
    static showVal(){
        return this.val;
    }
}

class Main2 extends Base{
    static showVal(){
        return this.val * 2
    }
}


var main1 = new Main1();
var main2 = new Main2();

main1.initialize(1);
main2.initialize(2);

console.log(main1.showVal());// should show 1
console.log(main2.showVal());// should show 4
```

Howeber this code shows the error like this below.

How can I solve this?

```
    Uncaught TypeError: Super expression must either be null or a function
```

Comment: `main1.initialize(1);` does not make sense, `initialize` is a static method. Did you mean `Main1.initialize(1);`?

Comment: I cannot reproduce the problem with the code you've shown. It only throws *TypeError: main1.initialize is not a function* (as expected, see my previous comment), nothing about the super expression.

Comment: "*There are two static classes `Main1` and `Main2`*" - no. Methods/fields/properties can be static (on the class) or per instance. The class itself cannot be "static".

Answer (score 1):

A class is a set with abilities and properties. In terms of abilities/properties, you have two main kinds:

- static (class-level)
- instance-level

Now, a `static` method is the ability of the class and not of its instances. Since you defined `initialize` as a `static` method, it will not be reachable via instances of the class, as it's not an instance-level, but a class-level ability (method, to be precise). So, I have fixed your code by making sure that `main1` and `main2` are the exact classes of `Main1` and `Main2` respectively instead of instances and then their static methods can be reached. If you want to use instances and use these abilities as instance-level abilities, then you can create instances, but then you will either need to modify these methods to instance-level methods, or, you will need to reach them through the class.

```js
class Base{
    static val;
    static initialize(x){
        this.val = x;
    }
}
class Main1 extends Base{
    static showVal(){
        return this.val;
    }
}

class Main2 extends Base{
    static showVal(){
        return this.val * 2
    }
}


var main1 = Main1;
var main2 = Main2;

main1.initialize(1);
main2.initialize(2);

console.log(main1.showVal());// should show 1
console.log(main2.showVal());// should show 4
```

Comment: AH, maybe I am confused with static class and instance. Thank you for your help I can sort out my brain!!